# Angular directive's link function not being called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a problem with AngularJS directive link function. It's not beeing called and it doesn't throw any error. Also the template in directive's return is not rendering :( Where should be problem? Thank you for answers!

```
angular.module('sampleApp.game').directive('gameCanvas', function($injector) {      
    console.log('Directive is working'); // this works,

    function linkFn(scope, ele, attrs) {
        console.log('Link function doesnt working :('); // but this not :(
    };

    return {
        scope: {},
        template: '<div class="blabla"></div>',
        link: linkFn
    }   
});
```

My html template file

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Play a game!</h1>
    <p>{{ tagline }}</p>   
    <div class="game-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to add `restrict: "C"` or any other restriction you want for it.

Comment: Nice! It works! but why? :D Why it didn't worked before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, directives are for Element and Attribute ('EA') only.  Define the restrict attribute as 'C'.  Best practice is to always define it explicitly.

```
angular.module('sampleApp.game').directive('gameCanvas', function($injector) {      
console.log('Directive is working'); // this works,

function linkFn(scope, ele, attrs) {
    console.log('Link function doesnt working :('); // but this not :(
};

return {
    scope: {},
    restrict: 'C', //'EA' by default
    template: '<div class="blabla"></div>',
    link: linkFn
}
```

});

Documented by Angular here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object.